# What is the most efficient way to convert a large db with ip addresses to countries without installing any database?

Tags: php, database, ip

I want to find out how many visitors are from my country.

What is the most efficient way to convert a large db with ip addresses to countries without installing any database? Or is there any other solution?

I used this api but the server response is too long...

```
     foreach ($loc as $row) {
        $ip = $row->last_ip;

         $country = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip='.$ip);
        if ($country == 'RO') {
            $num++;
        } 
     }
```

Can cURL help me with the server response problem? If yes, how can I use it?

Comment: If you don't want to use your own database use third-part API. Also it will be better if you show us structure of existing db.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about testing Geo::IP which works pretty well.
http://metacpan.org/pod/Geo::IP